# Metplotlib show error The number of FixedLocator locations, usually from a call to set_ticks, does not match the number of labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot graph and show the label in Matplotlib. I have some class to plot in same axis.

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
    
    
    x = [1,1,  # plot 2 value at X1
         2,2,2,2,  # plot 4 value at X2
         3,3,3,3,3,
         4,4,4,4,4,
         5,5,5,5,5,] 
    
    y = [0.04,0.005,  # value for plot at X1
         0.3, 0.03,0.02,0.06,  # value for plot at X2
         0.2,0.4,0.07,0.5, 0.009,
         0.1, 0.008, 0.3, 0.007,0.005,
         0.01,0.001,0.0004,0.0006,0.002]   
    
    classes = ['A',#0
               'B',#1
               'C',#2
               'D',#3
               'E',#4
               'F',#5
               'G',#6
               'H',#7
               'I',#8
               'J',#9
               'K',#10
               'L',#11
               'M']#12
] 
    values = [8,12,      # Class to plot at X1
              1,5,6,8,   # Class to plot at X2
              0,2,3,4,5,
              3,2,7, 11,12,
              1,4,10,11,12]
    
    my_xticks = ["X1","X2","X3","X4",
    "X5","X6","X7","X8",
    "X9","X10","X11","X12",
    "X13","X14","X15"]

    plt.xticks(x,my_xticks)
    
    scatter = plt.scatter(x, y, c=values)
    plt.legend(handles=scatter.legend_elements()[0], labels=classes)
```

when I run this code it show error like this. It have no error if I remove my_xticks. How to fix it?

```
ValueError: The number of FixedLocator locations (21), usually from a call to set_ticks, does not match the number of labels (15).
```

Comment: As is mentioned in the error msg, there are 15 values for `x` and 21 values for `my_xticks`. `plt.ticks()` expects the same number of values for ticks and ticklabels. You need to match the numbers for these two variables

Comment: How to match number? when I show value at X1 I cannot use list in x like this `x = [[1,1]` it show error `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'`

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do.... but if, for e.g. you add more labels to `my_ticks` ... like "X16", "X17", .... , "X21" and run the above code, it will work. Other option, reduce the number of values in `X`, `Y` and `values` to have length of 15 and it will work....

Comment: Your current `x` has many repeated values.  `plt.xticks` expects its first parameter to be a list of different x-positions. The number of labels should be exactly equal to the number of positions.  Maybe `plt.xticks([1,2,3,4,5],["X1","X2","X3","X4","X5"])` is what you want to achieve?